# Open private window in firefox with Alfred?

Tags: firefox, alfred

How can I open a private window in Firefox with Alfred?

I have the powerpack but I still cant figure out how to do this.

I think this package is out of date as I couldn't install it and its from 2011: 
http://derekallard.com/blog/post/launching-your-browsers-in-private-mode-with-alfred

I was able to install this one but its for safari and its buggy. It works if safari is closed but not if its already open:

http://www.packal.org/workflow/private-browsing

Comment: Well, did you install that extension? What was the result?

Comment: @Seth Ive updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a workflow that launches the following command suggested by [user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894):

```
open -a Firefox --args -private-window
```

Take a look [at this Apple SE question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201681/how-to-start-firefox-web-browser-from-terminal-in-private-mode):

A less clean way would be to create a separate workflow that launches Firefox, delays for a second, and then executes the private window hotkey (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (on macOS) or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (on Windows/Linux)).